# How to go about figuring out if a function is one to one or on to?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions

I'm having trouble grasping this concept when I think I get it, another problem shows up and it feels like the same logic doesn't work. But that shouldn't be the case no? So I feel like there's something I'm not completely understanding.
Though I feel like the changing domains or co-domains is what's throwing me off.

For example a problem such as:

Given $[0,∞) \to [8,∞)$

$f(x) = 5x^2+8$

Figure out if its a bijection.(which means both one to one and onto right?)

How do I go about figuring this out? What should I be looking at? I though I could just put $1$ & $-1$ into $x1$ and $x2$ and go from there to see if it's one to one, no? Math isn't my strongest subject so bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asserting that $f$ is injective is to assert that, if $x,y\in[0,\infty)$ and if $f(x)=f(y)$, then $\require{cancel}x=y$. You have\begin{align}f(x)=f(y)&\iff5x^2+\cancel8=5y^2+\cancel8\\&\iff\cancel5x^2=\cancel5y^2\\&\iff x^2=y^2\\&\iff x=y\text{ or }x=-y.\end{align}But, since $x,y\in[0,\infty)$, the only case in which $x=-y$ is when $x=y=0$; in particular, $x=y$. And, if $x,y>0$, then it follows from the previous computations that, again, $x=y$.

Concerning surjectivity, consider the equation $f(x)=y$ (with $y\in[8,\infty)$), that is, $5x^2+8=y$. Since\begin{align}5x^2+8=8&\iff5x^2=y-8\\&\iff x^2=\frac{y-8}5\\&\iff x=\sqrt{\frac{y-8}5},\end{align}the equation always has a solution. That is, $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Appreciate the quick reply! but how does 4y^2 turn to 5y^2 or better yet how did you get 4y^2?

Comment: That was a typo.

Comment: Gotcha! Had a feeling just wanted to make sure though. It's become a bit more clear to me though after this. As I realized my issue was in fact me not understanding how to properly use the domains. Properly gonna put in more practice but regardless thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.